# How do I copy a Python DataFrame conditionally to columns named partly in cells?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How does one select rows to change values on one column based on the contents of another column, and use the value in a cell of the selected rows to choose the column to fill?

I'm new to Python and not sure how to do things in a Pythonesque way. I've got a few columns from a data source that I am trying to munge into a different format.

For example, in the following, for rows where ProvincePolled=='Ontario', I would like to copy the CandidateA column content to 'Ontario CandidateA', and the CandidateB column content to 'Ontario CandidateB'.

And for the BC and Quebec rows, I would similarly like to copy over the values for the CandidateA and CandidateB columns to the columns named by concatenating the ProvincePolled cell and the names of those columns.

Finally, the rows where ProvincePolled=='Canada' will need to have the CandidateY column results copied to the respective 'ProvinceX CandidateY' columns (where ProvinceX in (Ontario, BC, Quebec) and Y in ('A','B').

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'ProvincePolled':['Ontario','Ontario','BC','Quebec','Canada'],
                  'CandidateA':[33.1,31.3,27.7,33.3,30.0],
                  'CandidateB':[12.1,15.3,28.7,11.3,18.0],
                  'Ontario CandidateA':[0.0,0,0,0,0],
                  'Ontario CandidateB':[0.,0,0,0,0],
                  'BC CandidateA':[0.,0,0,0,0],
                  'BC CandidateB':[0.,0,0,0,0],
                  'Quebec CandidateA':[0.,0,0,0,0],
                  'Quebec CandidateB':[0.,0,0,0,0],
                  })
df
```

Sorry about the formatting here:

```
ProvincePolled  CandidateA  CandidateB  Ontario CandidateA  Ontario CandidateB  BC CandidateA   BC CandidateB   Quebec CandidateA   Quebec CandidateB
0   Ontario 33.1    12.1    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   Ontario 31.3    15.3    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   BC  27.7    28.7    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   Quebec  33.3    11.3    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   Canada  30.0    18.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The following statement doesn't correctly determine the province column:

```
df.loc[df['ProvincePolled'] != 'Canada', df['ProvincePolled'] + ' CandidateA'] = df.loc[df['ProvincePolled'] != 'Canada', 'CandidateA']
```

as it results in KeyError: "['Canada CandidateA'] not in index".

I also tried defining a function

```
def fill_cols(row,cols,from_col):
  for col in cols:
    row[col] = from_col

df.loc[df['ProvincePolled'] != 'Canada'] = df.locdf['ProvincePolled'] != 'Canada'].apply(lambda x: fill_cols(x,['Ontario CandidateA','Quebec CandidateA','BC CandidateA'],x['CandidateA'])
```

But this didn't work either, yielding KeyError: ('CandidateA', 'occurred at index ProvincePolled').

Comment: Your descriptions is kind of long. I am little bit of lost from `ProvincePolled=='Canada' ` part because your `df` doesn't have any predefined columns(with `0` values) for them as in previous rows. Could you provided an expected output from the `df` you provided above?

Comment: Yes, there is not supposed to be a Canada column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is just a simple `pivot`, `update` and slicing assignment

```
df1 = df[['ProvincePolled', 'CandidateA', 'CandidateB']]
df2 = df1.pivot(columns='ProvincePolled')
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('{0[1]} {0[0]}'.format)
df.update(df2)
df.loc[df.ProvincePolled.eq('Canada'),
       df.columns.str.contains('\w+ +CandidateA')] = df.loc[df.ProvincePolled.eq('Canada'), 'CandidateA']
df.loc[df.ProvincePolled.eq('Canada'),
       df.columns.str.contains('\w+ +CandidateB')] = df.loc[df.ProvincePolled.eq('Canada'), 'CandidateB']

Out[173]:
  ProvincePolled  CandidateA  CandidateB  Ontario CandidateA  \
0        Ontario        33.1        12.1                33.1
1        Ontario        31.3        15.3                31.3
2             BC        27.7        28.7                 0.0
3         Quebec        33.3        11.3                 0.0
4         Canada        30.0        18.0                30.0

   Ontario CandidateB  BC CandidateA  BC CandidateB  Quebec CandidateA  \
0                12.1            0.0            0.0                0.0
1                15.3            0.0            0.0                0.0
2                 0.0           27.7           28.7                0.0
3                 0.0            0.0            0.0               33.3
4                18.0           30.0           18.0               30.0

   Quebec CandidateB
0                0.0
1                0.0
2                0.0
3               11.3
4               18.0
```

Comment: This looks like it is right, I will check in morning on real code and likely accept anser then.